# Form content is not shown during the execution of a process

Tags: vb.net, graphics, process

I've a main form `FormMain` which executes a process on button click.
When the button is clicked, first a border-less form `StatusForm` is shown and then the process starts. See code below.

```
Public Class FormMain

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Compiling..."
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.ForeColor = Color.White
    StatusStrip1.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue
    StatusForm.TopMost = True
    StatusForm.Show()

    RichTextBoxEditor.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Swaroop\Documents\temp\test.cpp")
    proc.CreateNoWindow = True
    proc.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.RedirectStandardInput = True
    proc.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    'proc.RedirectStandardError = True
    pr = Process.Start(proc)
    pr.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo off")
    pr.StandardInput.WriteLine("g++ ""C:\Users\Swaroop\Documents\temp\test.cpp""" & " -o " & """C:\Users\Swaroop\Documents\temp\test""")
    'pr.StandardInput.WriteLine(FileType & " " & """" & FileName & """" & " -o " & """" & Filepath & "\" & FileNameNoExt & """")
    pr.StandardInput.Close()
    RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText(pr.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())
    proc.RedirectStandardError = True
    RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText(pr.StandardError.ReadToEnd())

    If pr.StandardOutput.EndOfStream Then
        StatusForm.Close()
        compilationStatus()
        pr.StandardOutput.Close()
        pr.StandardError.Close()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub compilationStatus()
    If RichTextBoxConsole.Text.Contains("error") Then
        Dim MSplit As Array = Split(RichTextBoxConsole.Text, "error")
        Dim countWordError As Integer = MSplit.Length - 1
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Compilation failed with (" & countWordError.ToString & ") errors."
        StatusStrip1.BackColor = Color.Red
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.ForeColor = Color.White

    ElseIf RichTextBoxConsole.Text.Contains("warning") Then
        Dim MSplit As Array = Split(RichTextBoxConsole.Text, "warning")
        Dim countWordWarning As Integer = MSplit.Length - 1
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Compilation succeeded with (" & countWordWarning.ToString & ") warnings."
        StatusStrip1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.ForeColor = Color.White
    Else
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Compilation succeeded."
        StatusStrip1.BackColor = Color.Blue
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.ForeColor = Color.White
    End If

End Sub
End Class

Public Class StatusForm

Private Sub StatusForm_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Dim g As Graphics
    g = e.Graphics
    Dim p As Pen = New Pen(Color.Gray, 8)
    g.DrawRectangle(p, e.ClipRectangle)
    g.DrawString("Compiling...", New Font("Arial", 16), Brushes.Gray, 35, 37)
End Sub

End Class
```

The problem is when the form `StatusForm` is displayed on button click, the form is displayed without creating the graphics as described in the `StatusForm_Paint` sub. I mean a blank form is displayed. Also I tried removing the `DrawString` method and placed a label control in the form. When the button was clicked the same blank form was shown with the label's bounds area became transparent and see-through.

Comment: That's because everything after the call to `Show` is done on the UI thread, so that thread isn't available to paint your other form. One thread can only do one thing at a time. There are a number of specific options available, including calling async methods, e.g. `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync`. This issue is about more than changing a line or two of code though. It's about you understanding the principles of multi-threading and parallelism. You ought to do some reading on those subjects.

Comment: In the mean time, you might benefit from using [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567).